Let $D=\{z\in \Bbb C; 0<\Im z<\pi, z\not\in [0,\pi i/4]\cup [3\pi i/4,\pi i]\}$. How to find a conformal map from $D$ to the upper half plane?

Let $D=\{z\in \Bbb C; 0<\Im z<\pi, z\not\in [0,\pi i/4]\cup [3\pi i/4,\pi i]\}$. Here $\Im z$ is the imaginary part of $z$. How to find a conformal map from $D$ to the upper half plane?

My attempt: $e^z$ mapsto $D$ to $D_1=\{z; \Im z>0, z\not\in e^{i\tau}, \tau\in [0,\pi/4]\cup [3\pi/4,\pi]\}$, and $z^2$ mapsto $D_1$ to $\{z; z\not\in [0,\infty)\}\cup \{e^{i\tau}; \tau\in [0,\pi]\}$. Then ...

In the definition of $D$, you have $z\notin[0,\pi i/4]\cup[3\pi i/4,\pi i]$. What is meant by an interval $[a,b]$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$? i.e. is this meant to be a restriction on the imaginary component of $z$ instead?

@FinnT Yes...it is.

So is the region ${z=x+iy:x\in\mathbb{R},,,y\in(\pi/4,3\pi/4)}$?

@FinnT I'm inclined to read $[a,b]$ here as the straight line segment joining $a$ and $b$. So $D$ is an infinite strip with two slits cut into it.

I'm assuming that $D$ is simply the region of the upper half plane with $\mathrm{arg}(z)\in(\pi/4,3\pi/4)$, and with $\mathrm{Im}(z)<\pi$ - its current definition is not fully clear.
Now, $z^2:\Omega\rightarrow\Lambda$ is a conformal mapping where $\Omega=\{z\in\mathrm{C}:0<\mathrm{arg}(z)<\pi/2\}$ is mapped to $\Lambda=\{z\in\mathrm{C}:0<\mathrm{arg}(z)<\pi\}$. That is, $z^2$ simply doubles the argument of points in $\Omega$.
Naively, $z^2$ maps arguments in $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$ to $2\theta\in(0,\pi)$. We need a conformal map that takes arguments in $(\pi/4,3\pi/4)$ to $(0,\pi)$. A linear map between these is given by $\theta\mapsto2\theta-\pi/2$.
So, we need some conformal map $f:re^{i\theta}\mapsto f(r)e^{i(2\theta-\pi/2)}$. Of course, $e^{-i\pi/2}=-i$ and it's easy to convince yourself that $f(r)=r^2$ is sufficient.
So, $f(z)=-ir^2e^{i2\theta}=-iz^2$ should do the trick.
